# AJAX POST Request not calling Controller method in post route

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

My code gives me 500 Internal Server error when trying to make AJAX POST request. I've done the CSRF Token part.

This is my JS code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('#likeBtn').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    //Getting urlLink and activityId - works

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './mainView/postlike',
        data: {activityId : activityId},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.log(JSON.stringify("Exception: " + e));
        }
    });
});
```

This is my post Route :

```
Route::post('/mainView/postlike', 'ActivityController@postLike')->name('postLike')->middleware('auth');
```

This is my controller method :

```
public function postLike(){
    if(Request::ajax()){
        return Response::json(Request::all());
    }
}
```

This is my mainView.blade.php. I didn't really want to use a form but I tried anyway.

```
<form id="likeForm" method="POST" action="#">
    <input class="likeToken" type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <a id="likeBtn" data="{{ route('activity.like', ['activityId' => $activity->activity_id]) }}">
    <img src="IMG/icons/like.png" alt="likes">
    </a>{{ $activity->likes->count() }}
</form>
```

That being said, if I do this in my route, it outputs the message provided.

```
Route::post('/mainView/postlike', function(){
    if(Request::ajax()){
        echo "Hi";
    }
})->name('postLike')->middleware('auth');
```

It shows "Hi" when the like button is pressed

Comment: Error in server side script. Try to enable error feedback on your server.

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for the error.

Comment: It says, local.ERROR: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::ajax() should not be called statically {"userId":1,"email":"test@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Non-static method Illuminate\\Http\\Request::ajax() should not be called statically at <ControllerFile>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, you've posted the error message. To fix it, change this:

```
if(Request::ajax()){
```

to this:

```
if (request()->ajax()) {
```

For the second error:

```
response()->json(request()->all());
```

Also, you can inject `Request` class:

```
public function postLike(Request $request)
```

And use `$request` instead of `request()`

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim it means it works. You've fixed one error and this one is completely different error.

Comment: Actually, yes it works, I had to replace other Request uses as well. Thanks!

Comment: Also, do I need to have a form? Can I perform the AJAX operation without the form?

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim when you're using JS to send data, you can do it without a form.

Comment: One last thing, I'm sending activity_id through AJAX. How do I access it through $request?

Comment: @ShahlinIbrahim `request('activity_id')` or `request()->activity_id` or `$request->activity_id` if you inject `Request` class object.